# Unknown users within the Suggested Edits review queue

Tags: support, suggested-edits, users

On several occasions I have found that in the Suggested Edits review queue there are new (low-reputation) users who almost always suggest insignificant or irrelevant changes to questions or answers. Who are these users?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about the Suggested Edits review queue?

Comment: @Werner Yes, I have right. If my question it is not more clear in English language you are free to edit it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Suggested Edits review queue](//tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) contains edits that are suggested by members that have not reached 2,000 reputation. This limit is when the [Edit questions and answers privilege](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) kick in. Until that point, users could gain reputation (+2) from suggesting an edit that is eventually approved. This reputation gain (up to +1,000 reputation per user) could encourage new users trying to improve the site, but might be frivolous (hence being put up for review).

Comment: Thank you very much..always...Why they improved questions or answers with very modest or incorrect or unnecessary adjustments?

Comment: @Sebastiano: It's subjective. Some people feel they are improving the site (or the post) by changing some grammar. I was like as well when I started, thinking that any improvement is still an improvement. They don't know that things should be a more substantive (including tags, possibly the title, some formatting and grammar, say).